# Usage of prepositions with a relative

Tags: prepositions

Which sentence is the right one and why: "Service object through which asynchronous operations are dispatched" or "Service object which asynchronous operations are dispatched through". Please explain when is it allowed to put prepositions at the end of a sentence?

Comment: These sentences don't sound complete to me

Comment: This is a documentation block of a variable in a programming language. Whether the sentence is complete or not does not matter in this case I think. I'd just like to know the rules for using prepositions.

Comment: For example why is it possible to put a preposition at the end of a question, like "What are you looking for?"

Comment: https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/grammar/ending-sentences-with-prepositions may help with that

Comment: The first part of your question on which sentence is correct depends on the rest of the sentence.  Either could be correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idiomatic spoken version is:

> ... the service object (that) async operations are dispatched through...

It has a potentially reduced clause and a postponed preposition, and it drops the relative pronoun **which**.

The more formal written version is:

> ... the service object through which asynchronous operations are dispatched...

A small percentage of speakers are such practiced writers that they will use the second version even when speaking. But they are the exception, not the rule.

A simpler way to state it is to avoid the passive:

> .. the service object which dispatches asynchronous operations...